# Comparison of Similarity Measures

Tags: similarities, hamming-distance, jarowinkler-distance, monge-elkan-distance

Could anyone explain in simple words (and maybe with an example) What are the differences between Hamming Distance, Jaro, and Monge-Elkan in terms of quality data matching through the string similarity?